# Python (+SymPy): How to get the same result as in Mathematica?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I calculated the following using **Mathematica** and **Python**.

[image]

**Mathematica** with the following code

```
f[x_] = a*b/(a - b)^2*Exp[-r*x] (Exp[-b*x] - Exp[-a*x]) (a*Exp[-b*x] - b*Exp[-a*x])
Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, r > 0}, Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

gives a rather nice result:

[image]

But, the following Python (with SymPy) code

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
x = symbols('x')
a, b, r = symbols('a b r', positive=True)
fun = a*b/((a-b)**2) * exp(-r*x) * (exp(-b*x) - exp(-a*x)) * (a*exp(-b*x) - b*exp(-a*x))
simplify(integrate(fun, (x, 0, oo)))
```

generates a rather messy result:

[image]

What am I missing in the Python code to obtain the same result in Mathematica? Or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [`cancel`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#cancel) can be used to cancel fractions:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
x = symbols('x')
a, b, r = symbols('a b r', positive=True)
fun = a*b/((a-b)**2) * exp(-r*x) * (exp(-b*x) - exp(-a*x)) * (a*exp(-b*x) - b*exp(-a*x))
factor(cancel(integrate(fun, (x, 0, oo)))
```

gives

```
      a⋅b⋅(2⋅a + 2⋅b + r)
───────────────────────────────
(2⋅a + r)⋅(2⋅b + r)⋅(a + b + r)
```